# Multiple separate but similar ODE systems in R

Tags: r, ode

I'm fairly new to R and am facing the following problem:

I have four different independent ODE systems such that

```
x' = a1*y - b1*x
y' = a2*x - b2*y

x' = a1 - b1*x/y
y' = a2*x - b2*y

x' = a1*y - b1*x
y' = a2 - b2*y/x

x' = a1 - b1*x/
y' = a2 - b2*y/x
```

Each system shares some terms with another system. Now I'd like to solve them all and compare their time courses.

Is there an efficient way of implementing this without having to type out every  single term? I should note that in reality I have much more ODEs than in this toy example.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest writing out a master gradient function with all possible terms, e.g. x' = c1 + c2*x + c3*y + c4*x/y, y= c5 + c6*x + c7*y + c8*y/x, and mapping parameters appropriately (e.g. for system 1 c1=0,c2=-b1,c3=a1,c4=0,c5=0,c6=a2,c7=-b2,c8=0)

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. Could you please give a code example @BenBolker